# Entity framework issue with WCF and IIS

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, entity-framework, iis

I have a WCF service, a MS SQL database, and the Visual Studio 2008 development environment all in one machine.
The operating system is Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7 on it.
The IIS 7 hosts my WCF service and the service is connecting to a database using Microsoft Entity Framework. Currently, I'm testing the WCF service using the WCF Test Client program from Microsoft.

The problem is that when I declare an entity like this in my WCF method:

```
NewTestDBEntities db = new NewTestDBEntities();
```

the WCF service client shows an error if I connecting to the WCF service hosting on IIS.

This is the error message form the WCF service client:

*Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.*

I know this line throws an error because if I take this line away, then the WCF call completes.

I also tried to test the WCF service by running the debugger (the WCF service client is connected to the ASP.NET Development Server, not IIS), and this line of code

```
NewTestDBEntities db = new NewTestDBEntities();
```

runs without error. Does anyone know why this happen?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WCF service is hosted in IIS - but did you copy the connection string needed for EF4 into the relevant `web.config`, too??

If just the creation of the object context (the `NewTestDBEntities`) fails off the bat, it's typically because the connection info isn't available to your host application (here: IIS).

Comment: @peter: would you care to share how you solved the issue?? Someone else might benefit from that

Comment: I have a ASP .NET project in the same solution as my WCF service project. The ASP .NET project basically referenced the WCF project so I can put on to IIS. Thus, there will be two .config file. 
I have the connection string in my config file in WCF service project but not the config file in the ASP .NET project. That's the promblem that I had. So the solution is to copy the connection string to the config file in the ASP .NET project. That's it!